# JS table add a new line and how to add the pattern in this new line? Like change into < tr class=”trd0”>

Tags: javascript, dom

JS:

```
var tab = document.getElementById("tab"); 
var newTr = tab.insertRow(-1);   
newTr.id = "tr_" + trId; 
var newTdContent = newTr.insertCell(1); //  first line
var newTdCaoZuo  = newTr.insertCell(2); //   second line      
// set the data of two line  
newTdContent.innerHTML  = "<textarea rows='5' cols='40'name='getContent' id='getContent'>" + content.value + "</textarea>";  
newTdCaoZuo.innerHTML  = "<input type='button' onclick='moveTr("+trId+")' value='remove'>";
```

the new line in table is different from the other line. The pattern of new added line is limited.

```
table 

<tr class="trd0"> 
<td>..</td> 
<tr>
```

I do not want to add the newTr pattern like class="trd0". How to achieve it？

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Please clarify your question. Are you trying to create a zebra-style table? Do you want to alternate between classes?

Comment: Are you asking how to set the "class" of the row? It's just `newRow.className = value;`, where *value* is the new class, or empty string if the row should have no class.